# Why C++ Unity builds get smaller binary size

Tags: c++

The follow files:

```
1.cc include common.h 
2.cc include common.h
unity_build.cc include 1.cc and 2.cc
```

I can understand that the time to compile unity_build.cc will be faster than compiling 1.cc and 2.cc separately, because common.h is only expanded once, so less code needs to be compiled in total.
But why the **binary file size is smaller**? Didn't the linker remove the same symbols?

Comment: "faster" / "less code" than what? You seem to compare it to something without saying with what you compare

Comment: What size do you compare? File size of the binary? Code size? Compare with what? BTW: A symbol in one compilation unit is not the same as a symbol with the very same name in another compilation unit.

Comment: "File size of the binary"

Comment: Perhaps because with unity build you are essentially automatically getting Link Time Optimization + less TU statics.

Comment: What confuses me is the difference in the size of the linked binary using unity build, not the time

Comment: Link Time Optimization is a size+performance optimization which happens during *link time*. I guess this is one of those confusing english wording. S.A. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319579/what-are-the-drawbacks-of-single-source-project-structures/46321758#46321758

Comment: the file size of the binary is not the size of th binary itself. The files also include debug information, linker infos and a lot more. To compare the real executable part in the file, you have to use e.g. `size <file>` on linux/unix.