# Avoid circular dependence of template class in C++

Tags: c++

It is well know that circular dependence is a bad practice.

Suppose we have two class `A` and `B`. Each class need using other as an input variable of member function.

I know we can using forward declaration to avoid circular dependence, that is:

```
// A.h
class B;
class A
{
public:
   void doWithB(B& b);
   ...
private:
};
```

```
// A.cpp
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
void A::doWithB(B& b)
{
   ...
}
```

```
// B.h
class A;
class B
{
public:
   void doWithA(A& a);
   ...
private:
};
```

```
// B.cpp
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
void B::doWithA(A& a)
{
   ...
}
```

However, if class `A` and `B` is template class, so the class should be implemented in headfile. One implement is that:

```
//A.h
#include "B.h"
template<typename Type>
class A
{
public:
void doWithB(B<Type> &b)
{
   ...
}
private:
};
```

```
//B.h
#include "A.h"
template<typename Type>
class B
{
public:
void doWithA(A<Type> &a)
{
   ...
}
private:
};
```

We can see that `A.h` include `B.h`, and `B.h` include `A.h`.
At these case, how can we avoid the circular dependence?

The practical class example is `Array` and `LinkedList`. They are template class. I need the function that transfer `Array` To `LinkedList`, and transfer `LinkedList` to `Array`. So I face the problem.

Thanks in advance. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please take your shown code closer to what you are trying. Surely you can make one of the two classes a template class?

Comment: I modify the code. Yes. I mean two template class. template class A and template class B.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with circular dependence. Related: [How to declare/define interdependent templates in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45402913/how-to-declare-define-interdependent-templates-in-c/45403262)

Comment: Quick question, is it possible to use the typical STL approach of taking generic ranges instead of specific container types?