# Circular dependency problems with templated class

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

I have `EventBus` class which manages callbacks and `EBHandle` class which is intended to automatically cleanup callbacks when object that added them is destroyed. So, i think that circular dependency is justified here. Also i have `BaseEvent`, but it's not important, just so that code can run.

```
#pragma once

#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
#include <typeindex>

struct BaseEvent {
    BaseEvent() = default;
    virtual ~BaseEvent() = default;
};

class EventBus;

class EBHandle {
private:
    int m_key = -1;
    bool m_isRemoved = false;
    std::type_index m_type = typeid(int);
    EventBus* m_eventBus = nullptr;

public:
    EBHandle(EventBus *eventBus, std::type_index type, int key);;

    void remove();
};

class EventBus {
    std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::unordered_map<int, std::function<void(const BaseEvent &)>>> m_callbacks;
    int m_keyCounter = 0;
public:
    EventBus() = default;

    template<typename EventType>
    EBHandle addEventListener(const std::function<void(const EventType &)> &callback) {
        // passing m_callback by copy is necessary. otherwise if callback passed to addEventListener by reference and it is destroyed, lambda will have dangling reference
        auto wrapper = [callback](const BaseEvent &baseEvent) {
            callback(static_cast<const EventType &>(baseEvent));
        };
        std::type_index type = typeid(EventType);
        m_callbacks[type][m_keyCounter] = wrapper;
        return {this, type, m_keyCounter++};
    };

    template<typename EventType>
    void removeEventListener(int key) {
        m_callbacks[typeid(EventType)].erase(key);
    };

    void removeEventListener(std::type_index type, int key) {
        m_callbacks[type].erase(key);
    };

    void emit(const BaseEvent &event) {
        auto &eventTypeCallbacks = m_callbacks[typeid(event)];
        for (auto &pair: eventTypeCallbacks) {
            pair.second(event);
        }
    };

    EventBus(const EventBus &) = delete;
    EventBus &operator=(const EventBus &) = delete;
    EventBus(EventBus &&) = delete;
    EventBus &operator=(EventBus &&) = delete;
};

EBHandle::EBHandle(EventBus *eventBus, std::type_index type, int key) : m_key(key), m_type(type), m_eventBus(eventBus) {}

void EBHandle::remove() {
    m_eventBus->removeEventListener(m_type, m_key);
    m_isRemoved = true;
}
```

While trying to break dependency, I have first tried splitting declarations and definitions into .cpp and .h files. Then realized that my methods are templated. Then tried to do it like in code above (in single file), and it works. However, i want to split EBHandle and EventBus to different files. Answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47810018/template-circular-dependency-seperate-classes-in-different-files) says that it's doable. I've tried it:

EventBus.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
#include <typeindex>
#include "EBHandle.h"

struct BaseEvent {
    BaseEvent() = default;
    virtual ~BaseEvent() = default;
};

class EventBus {
    std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::unordered_map<int, std::function<void(const BaseEvent &)>>> m_callbacks;
    int m_keyCounter = 0;
public:
    EventBus() = default;

    template<typename EventType>
    EBHandle addEventListener(const std::function<void(const EventType &)> &callback) {
        // passing m_callback by copy is necessary. otherwise if callback passed to addEventListener by reference and it is destroyed, lambda will have dangling reference
        auto wrapper = [callback](const BaseEvent &baseEvent) {
            callback(static_cast<const EventType &>(baseEvent));
        };
        std::type_index type = typeid(EventType);
        m_callbacks[type][m_keyCounter] = wrapper;
        return {this, type, m_keyCounter++};
    };

    template<typename EventType>
    void removeEventListener(int key) {
        m_callbacks[typeid(EventType)].erase(key);
    };

    void removeEventListener(std::type_index type, int key) {
        m_callbacks[type].erase(key);
    };

    void emit(const BaseEvent &event) {
        auto &eventTypeCallbacks = m_callbacks[typeid(event)];
        for (auto &pair: eventTypeCallbacks) {
            pair.second(event);
        }
    };

    EventBus(const EventBus &) = delete;
    EventBus &operator=(const EventBus &) = delete;
    EventBus(EventBus &&) = delete;
    EventBus &operator=(EventBus &&) = delete;
};
```

EBHandle.h:

```
class EventBus;
class EBHandle {
private:
    int m_key = -1;
    bool isRemoved = false;
    std::type_index m_type = typeid(int);
    EventBus* m_eventBus = nullptr;

public:
    EBHandle(EventBus *eventBus, std::type_index type, int key);

    void remove();
};

#include "EventBus.h"

EBHandle::EBHandle(EventBus *eventBus, std::type_index type, int key) : m_key(key), m_type(type), m_eventBus(eventBus) {};

void EBHandle::remove() {
    m_eventBus->removeEventListener(m_type, m_key);
    isRemoved = true;
}
```

I'm sorry it's so much code. I didn't want to miss anything important.

I am still getting "invalid use of incomplete type" errors in place where removeEventListener is called in EBHandle
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just move the member function definitions into a separate source file. See [demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FSzV4qQUK7yCvw8l) as shown in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77836755/12002570).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move the member function definitions of `EBHandle` into a separate source file as shown below. [Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/hMJpuovDv)

**EBHandle.cpp**

```
//#include "EBHandle.h" //this is not needed. The program will work without this because EventBus.h includes EBHandle.h
#include "EventBus.h"
EBHandle::EBHandle(EventBus *eventBus, std::type_index type, int key) : m_key(key), m_type(type), m_eventBus(eventBus) {};

void EBHandle::remove() {
    m_eventBus->removeEventListener(m_type, m_key);
    isRemoved = true;
}
```

**EBHandle.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <typeindex>
class EventBus;
class EBHandle {
private:
    int m_key = -1;
    bool isRemoved = false;
    std::type_index m_type = typeid(int);
    EventBus* m_eventBus = nullptr;

public:
    EBHandle(EventBus *eventBus, std::type_index type, int key);

    void remove();
};
```

**EventBus.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
#include <typeindex>
#include "EBHandle.h"

struct BaseEvent {
    BaseEvent() = default;
    virtual ~BaseEvent() = default;
};

class EventBus {
    std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::unordered_map<int, std::function<void(const BaseEvent &)>>> m_callbacks;
    int m_keyCounter = 0;
public:
    EventBus() = default;

    template<typename EventType>
    EBHandle addEventListener(const std::function<void(const EventType &)> &callback) {
        // passing m_callback by copy is necessary. otherwise if callback passed to addEventListener by reference and it is destroyed, lambda will have dangling reference
        auto wrapper = [callback](const BaseEvent &baseEvent) {
            callback(static_cast<const EventType &>(baseEvent));
        };
        std::type_index type = typeid(EventType);
        m_callbacks[type][m_keyCounter] = wrapper;
        return {this, type, m_keyCounter++};
    };

    template<typename EventType>
    void removeEventListener(int key) {
        m_callbacks[typeid(EventType)].erase(key);
    };

    void removeEventListener(std::type_index type, int key) {
        m_callbacks[type].erase(key);
    };

    void emit(const BaseEvent &event) {
        auto &eventTypeCallbacks = m_callbacks[typeid(event)];
        for (auto &pair: eventTypeCallbacks) {
            pair.second(event);
        }
};
};
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FSzV4qQUK7yCvw8l)