# 'Head' and 'Tail' were not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to create a Doubly Linked List and respective node class and am having an issue trying to add the data types of head and tail to my IntDLList class. I'm not quite sure what I missed, but an error is occurring stating that both head and tail were not declared, and that my Node class does not take a type. Any help is appreciated!

Edit: This does not seem to be a duplicate question, I looked at the other answers and trying to resolve an invalid use of incomplete type did not solve the same issue as my name type error.

IntDLList

```
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class IntDLList {
public:
       IntDLList() {
           head=tail=0; // error: 'head' was not declared in this scope (& same for tail)
       }
       ~IntDLList();
       int isEmpty() {
           return head==0; // error: 'head' was not declared in this scope
       }
       void addToDLLHead(const T&);
       void addToDLLTail(const T&);
       T deleteFromDLLHead();
       T deleteFromDLLTail();
       void deleteDLLNode(const T&);
       bool isInList(const T&) const;
       void showList();
private:
       IntDLLNode<T> *head, *tail; //error: IntDLLNode does not name a type
};
```

IntDLLNode

```
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class IntDLLNode {
    friend class IntDLList;
    public:
        IntDLLNode() {next = prev = 0;}
        IntDLLNode(const T& el, IntDLLNode *n = 0, IntDLLNode *p = 0) {
            info = el;
            next = n;
            prev = p;

        }
    protected:
         T info; 
         IntDLLNode<T> *next,*prev;
    private:

};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving a Circular Dependency between Template Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353831/resolving-a-circular-dependency-between-template-classes)

Comment: Looked at the possible duplicate and I believe that my classes don't demonstrate any circular dependency

Comment: The error `IntDLLNode does not name a type` means that either you forgot to `#include` the header where `IntDLLNode` is defined, or both headers include each other either directly or indirectly, which is a circular dependency.

Comment: @JohnHardingII Your classes obviously depend on each other (`IntDLList<T>` has members of type `IntDLLNode<T> *` and `IntDLLNode<T>` wants to be friends with `IntDLList<T>`), so you have a circular dependency chain. Adding a forward declaration as suggested in an answer to the other question makes things compile.

Comment: Live demo: https://ideone.com/v07ReY

Comment: That makes sense, I can see the dependency. @melpomene Thank you for the live demo. Added the forward, and the only issue I have now is the compiler is saying that "IntDLList is not a class template" where it is declared as a friend class in IntDLLNode

Comment: @JohnHardingII Did you see the change I made to that line? In my code it's `friend class IntDLList<T>;` (note the `<T>`). If that's not the issue, is the declaration of `IntDLList` visible where you declare `IntDLLNode` (header is included, etc)?

Comment: @melpomene, yes that was added- just a moment

Comment: @melpomene For some reason including the list class in my node header was not enough, it needed to be directly included in the class- but we're up in functioning now. Thank you for the help. I'll accept as answer if you add it