# How can I fix this callback include problem?

Tags: c++, callback, include

I am kind of new to C++ (and StackOverflow). I am trying to get something to work, but I have some `#include` problems.

I want to call a callback I made ([from here](http://www.tutok.sk/fastgl/callback.html)), but I am struggling to do this.

This is my code so far. When I include `child.hpp` in the `someclass.hpp` file (because it needs information about `Child` for `Callback<Child>`), it has a looped include and the compiler crashes.

I have read about forward declarations (would be `class Child;` in the `someclass.hpp` file), and after trying I figured out this works, but I also read different opinions about this.

I have all `.hpp` files guarded with `#ifndef CLASSNAME #define CLASSNAME ... #endif`

Do I need to change my entire design, or what is the best option in my case?

base.hpp

```cpp
#include "someclass.hpp"

class Base
{
    protected:
        unique_ptr<SomeClass> someClass;
};
```

base.cpp

```cpp
#include "base.hpp"

Base::Base()
{
    this->someClass = make_unique<SomeClass>();
}
```

child.hpp

```cpp
#include "base.hpp"

class Child : public Base
{
    public:
        void callbackFunction(std::string data);
        unique_ptr<Callback<Child>> callback;
};
```

child.cpp

```cpp
#include "child.hpp"

void Child::callbackFunction(std::string data)
{
    /*does something*/
}

Child::Child()
{
    this->callback = make_unique<Callback<Child>>(this, &Child::callbackFunction);
    //I can call this->callback->call(data); here without problems
    
    this->someClass->setCallback(this->callback);
  //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ == base.someClass

}
```

someclass.hpp

```cpp
#include "child.hpp" // < does crash compiler due to loop
//> someclass.hpp uses child.hpp
//> child.hpp uses base.hpp
//> base.hpp uses someclass.hpp
// and thus loop

class SomeClass
{
    public:
        void someFunction(std::string data);
        void setCallback(unique_ptr<Callback<Child>> callback);
        unique_ptr<Callback<Child>> callbackInstance;
};
```

someclass.cpp

```cpp
//not 100% sure about the type of this parameter
void setCallback(unique_ptr<Callback<Child>> callback)
{
    this->callbackInstance = callback;
}

void SomeClass::someFunction(std::string data)
{
    //here I want to call this "Child::callbackFunction" which should go like "this->callbackInstance->call(data)" ?
}
```

also in someclass.hpp

```cpp
template<class T>
class Callback
{
    public:
        Callback(T* instance, void (T::*function)(std::string))
        {
            this->callbackInstance = instance;
            this->callback = function;
        }
        void call(std::string data)
        {
            (callbackInstance->*callback)(data);
        }
    private:
        T *callbackInstance;
        void (T::*callback)(std::string);
};
```

Comment: `#include_once`?

Comment: I believe you are saying you have a circular include problem. Can you put `template<class T> class Callback` in its own header?

Comment: Yeah I can put it in its own header, but the include problem would be still the same since the callback needs information about the child class

Comment: What does "the compiler crashes" look like?  Is there a message?

Comment: Related; [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353831/resolving-a-circular-dependency-between-template-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353831/resolving-a-circular-dependency-between-template-classes)

Comment: the compiler crashs gives says "expected class-name before '{' token on child.hpp", if i remove this ```#include "child.cpp"``` from ```someclass.hpp```, it compiles fine

Comment: You said you are new to C++, but I presume you are not new to programming.  You may want to take a look into Boost [Signals2](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/signals2.html), which is signals/slots for C++.

Comment: I am not able to use boost due to a closed environment

Comment: ***the compiler crashs gives says "expected class-name before '{' token on child.hpp",*** We would not call that a compiler crash. We would call this an error message. A compiler crash could be a bug in the compiler itself.

Comment: `Callback<Child>` does not need to know what `Child` actually looks like, since `Callback` merely contains pointers and nothing else, so forward declarations should work just fine. Also, `someclass.hpp` should be including `child.hpp` not `child.cpp`. `base.hpp` include `someclass.hpp`? You did not show what `base.hpp` looks like

Comment: @Bart Can you also add `Base.hpp` and `Base.cpp` to your question and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yeah, **```someclass.hpp``` should be including ```child.hpp``` not ```child.cpp```** was a typo in my question. I changed ```child.cpp``` to ```child.hpp``` in my question. I think describing ```base.hpp``` is not important information since it is only a base class for ```Child``` and for now, there is nothing realy more inside it (except the ```#include "someclass.hpp"```). Anyway, should I use a forward declaration in stead of the ```#include "child.hpp"``` in the ```someclass.hpp```?

Comment: @Bart If you can add `Base.hpp` and `Base.cpp` then i will be able to see exactly where you're going wrong and provide the exact solution. Currently, since you have not provided us with these files so i have to make a guess for how those files looks like. And i can't post an answer based on some guess. So please provide those files(which are very important) to this question

Comment: I have provided the ```base.hpp``` and ```base.cpp```

Comment: @Bart Now i have added the solution as an answer to *"expected class-name before '{' token on child.hpp"*. Check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To **solve** the mentioned error(*"expected class-name before '{' token on child.hpp"*) you should **remove** the `#include "someclass.hpp"` from **base.hpp** and replace it with a **forward declaration** for `class SomeClass` as shown below.

**base.hpp**

```
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H
//NO NEED TO INCLUDE someclass.hpp
#include <memory>
class SomeClass;//FORWARD DECLARE SomeClass
class Base
{
    std::unique_ptr<SomeClass> someClass; 
    public:
    //add declaration for default constructor 
    Base();
};
#endif
```

**base.cpp**

```
#include "base.hpp"
#include "someclass.hpp"

//other things here

Base::Base()
{
    this->someClass = std::make_unique<SomeClass>();
}
```

**child.hpp**

```
#ifndef CHILD_H
#define CHILD_H
#include "base.hpp"
#include <memory>
#include "someclass.hpp"

class Child : public Base
{
    public:
        void callbackFunction(std::string data);
        std::unique_ptr<Callback<Child>> callback;
        //add declaration for default constrcutor 
        Child();
};
#endif
```

**child.cpp**

```
#include "child.hpp"

void Child::callbackFunction(std::string data){
    /*does something*/
}

Child::Child()
{
    this->callback = std::make_unique<Callback<Child>>(this, &Child::callbackFunction);
    //I can call this->callback->call(data); here without problems
}
```

**someclass.hpp**

```
#ifndef SOMECLASS_H
#define SOMECLASS_H
#include <string>
//REMOVED include child.hpp from here
class SomeClass
{
    public:
        void someFunction(std::string data);

        //I think I need an instance of Callback<Child> here?
};
template<class T>
class Callback
{
    public:
        Callback(T* instance, void (T::*function)(std::string))
        {
            this->callbackInstance = instance;
            this->callback = function;
        }
        void call(std::string data)
        {
            (callbackInstance->*callback)(data);
        }
    private:
        T *callbackInstance;
        void (T::*callback)(std::string);
};
#endif
```

**someclass.cpp**

```
#include "someclass.hpp"
void SomeClass::someFunction(std::string data)
{
    //here I want to call this "Child::callbackFunction" which should go like "this->callbackInstance->call(data)" ?
}
```

The above program compiles and executes successfully as can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/xzD0vx6cC4).

#### Summary

Some of the changes that i made are listed below:

- Removed unnecessary includes
- Added declarations for default constructor in child.hpp and base.hpp
- Added **include guards** in all headers.

Comment: Is it bad practice what I did? aka, including other ```.hpp``` files inside a ```.hpp``` file?

Comment: Also do I need to include the ```someClass.hpp``` in also the ```child.cpp```? Because if I dont, I get a ```"invalid use of incomplete type 'class SomeClass'``` inside ```child.hpp``` while compiling

Comment: @Bart I have added other files also in my answer. Check it out. I have written comments wherever i have made the changes. The output of the modified program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/xzD0vx6cC4).

Comment: @Bart It is not a bad practice to include other `.hpp` files inside a `.hpp` file. Just include the files that are really necessary and also keep track(meaning take care of) of **cyclic dependency**.

Comment: Ok, I see you removed the ```child.hpp``` include from ```someclass.hpp```. But if I want to call the callback from the ```Callback<Child> callbackInstance``` in ```someclass.cpp```, then it is beter to use a forward decleration or include ```child.hpp``` in the ```someclass.hpp``` file?

Comment: @Bart If you want to call the callback from `Callback<Child> callbackInstance` in **someclass.cpp** then you should add  `#include "child.hpp"` inside **someclass.cpp**. Note in `.cpp` files you can safely(without worrying) include `.hpp` files. It is only when you include `.hpp` files in other `.hpp` files that you have to take care of cyclic dependency. Also i would recommend using a separate header file for your `templates`.

Comment: Yes I am planning to move the template ```Callback<>``` to its own ```.hpp``` file. Do I understand it correctly that if I include a ```.hpp``` in a ```.cpp``` file, that I have to add the forward deflaration on the ```.hpp``` file for function declaration that uses a class form a sepperate class as parameter or return type?

Comment: @Bart Basically yes.